# Django Show Password Checkbox

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am looking to use Django to create a form with a password field that can be toggled to be hidden or shown. This functionality can be seen on MailChimp at https://login.mailchimp.com/signup. Does anyone know how such a field could be created?

Comment: You don't need Django for it. You can do some js what toggles the input type from password to text by the password field.

Comment: thank you! this was no problem at all using javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's just purely javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reveal()
{
if(document.getElementById('box').checked)
   {document.getElementById("pw").type='text';}
else
document.getElementById("pw").type='password';
}
</script>   

<input type="checkbox" id="box" onclick ="reveal()">    
<input type="password" id="pw">
```

Comment: To make this work with Django's builtin auth_views.LoginView, you can change "pw" to "id_password" in this answer which is django's password field's id